# Draw to ImageView while move and zoom

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, draw, move

If the ImageView would be fitXY and not matrix every drawn pixel would be correct.

But I need a matrix view where you can zoom and move the picture and on top of it mark things on the picture while doing that.

Here's the problem that the drawn pixels on the image aren't correct if the picture is moved or actually zoomed.

So now my question is how and where I have to build the event.getX and event.getY formula for every situation to solve this?

Thank you for your help!

Code:

```
@SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility", "SetTextI18n"})
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // handle touch events here
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            then = (long) System.currentTimeMillis();
            cx = event.getX();
            cy = event.getY();
        }

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                mode = DRAG;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                   savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
               }
                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
               break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                   matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                    float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                   matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
               }
                else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);

                }
                    float[] values = new float[9];
                    matrix.getValues(values);
                    float scaleX = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                    float scaleY = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

                    if(scaleX <= 1f) {
                        matrix.postScale((1f)/scaleX, (1f)/scaleY, mid.x, mid.y);
                    } else if(scaleX >= 3) {
                        matrix.postScale((3f)/scaleX, (3f)/scaleY, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                int longClickDuration = 2000;
                if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - then) > longClickDuration) {
                    if (pictureadded) {
                    txtQueen.setText("Queens:");
                    countQueen.setText(String.valueOf(queencount));
                    txtWorker.setText("Workers:");
                    countWorker.setText(String.valueOf(workercount));
                    txtBrut.setText("Brut:");
                    countBrut.setText(String.valueOf(brutcount));

                    Bitmap bitmap = imgGallery.getDrawingCache();

                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

                        if (queensselected) {
                            queencount++;
                            countQueen.setText(String.valueOf(queencount));
                            paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                            canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, 10, paint);
                            imgGallery.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                        }
                        if (workersselected) {
                            workercount++;
                            countWorker.setText(String.valueOf(workercount));
                            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                            canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, 10, paint);
                            imgGallery.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                        if (brutselected) {
                            brutcount++;
                            countBrut.setText(String.valueOf(brutcount));
                            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                            canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, 10, paint);
                            imgGallery.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

        Bitmap bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return true;
    }

// --Commented out by Inspection START (06.07.2023 19:41):
//    public void ButtonClick(){
//
//        fin.setImageBitmap(bmap);
//    }
// --Commented out by Inspection STOP (06.07.2023 19:41)
    /**
     * Determine the space between the first two fingers
     */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        float s=x * x + y * y;
        return (float)Math.sqrt(s);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
     */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }
```

Not much. I tried some normal operators.

Comment: Bonus: How is it possible to limit move so that the picture can't get completely out of the view?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution just by adding this:

```
// calculate inverse matrix
Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
imgGallery.getImageMatrix().invert(inverse);
float[] touchPoint = new float[] {event.getX(), event.getY()};
inverse.mapPoints(touchPoint);
```

And call

```
drawCanvas.drawCircle(touchPoint[0], touchPoint[1], 10, paint);
imgGallery.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```